# php two equal rows, but only show the one with a extra info

Tags: php, sql

Hi so I'm fetching in two almost identical rows from my db

[image]

So what I what do do is to check if there is two equal rows with the same name for extra_field if there is, it should only show the row where it has the bku_id.

Here is the object in php, where I want the code to execute that:
[image]

Comment: Do you want to do this in PHP or the query

Comment: @RiggsFolly Where it makes most sense, so if you can do it in the query fine, if not then in php

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL you can use this query -

```
SELECT * FROM <your_table> GROUP BY extra_field HAVING bku_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: i tried SELECT TOP (1000) [id]
      ,[extra_field]
      ,[value]
      ,[job_id]
      ,[bku_id]
  FROM [dbo].[jobs_input_fields]
  GROUP BY extra_field 
  HAVING bku_id IS NOT NULL

But gettig this error Column 'dbo.jobs_input_fields.bku_id' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.